# How do I post a file over HTTP via public API in ASP NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, api

I have a web application. I am using C#. I have existing methods in my API for various things but all only submit and return bool/int/strings.

All of my API methods have the directive
    System.ServiceModel.OperationContract
All the parameters are of
    System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember

I would like to be able to receive a posted file over HTTP. Apologies if this is a very simple question, but I'm not sure where to start so I don't know what to google. All I've been finding is people attempting to save a HttpPostedFile after submitting it in a form. 
Thanks in advance for any help.

**EDIT:** this will be called from an iPhone application. Not via the browser on the iPhone
**Basically**, I would like to do this: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/upload.api.html

Answer (score 1):

Your question is somewhat confusing.  But if you are asking how to receive a file via HTTP in an ASP.NET web app... the answer is the FileUpload control.  It doesn't really matter what browser (iPhone) the client is using.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is not what I am asking though. I don't think I've worded my question correctly. The iPhone will not be using a browser, they will be using an application made specifically to contact my application via a public API (for example like what flickr has: http://www.flickr.com/services/api/). I have no problems creating most methods in the API, my question is how/can I receive a file over this.

Answer (score 0):

Are you submitting the file via a web application or a desktop app?

Comment: iPhone application at the moment. But future intentions include other mobile devices, and a desktop application.

Comment: You can encode chunks of data as base64 and send them to the server in separate calls (using POST) as parameters of the call. I can't help you with the iPhone code but for reading parameters on the server side all you need is Request[paramName] (for POST) or Request.Params[paramName] (for GET calls).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try it. I was hoping for some native way of accomplishing this though! This method seems like it will be quite long.